# Moving to Android from a .NET background - terminology analogies

Tags: android, .net, android-intent

I'm moving to Android from .NET - can anyone give me a yes/no answer for all of these items in the list?

1. An Intent is akin to a Win32 message that can be broadcast to all active "activities" (the WPARAM and LPARAM flavour of message in Win32), but the activity registers what intents they are interested in.
2. An activity is not an independent thread. All activities contained within an app, no matter how many there are, are within the same process, yes? If not, can you explain?
3. If I call startActivity() that means the current activity is paused and no code executes in it, yes? Until the back button is pressed, that is, when the paused activity is popped from the stack "resumes" again. Or is the activity unloaded and then re-created?
4. startActivityWithResultCode keeps the parent activity around until the child activity ends. Could you say activities working in this way are akin in some ways to ASP.NET pages (.aspx)" using Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To give answer to your question a person must have knowledge of both .NET and android

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer those questions although 
I've limited knowledge of .net.

1. Yes, though by default the activities are registered to all Intent call from the same application, which uses their direct classname.
2. Yes for this  again. The activities run in a single process, if belongs to a single app.
3. On calling of `startActivity`, the activity goes in Pause state, however onlt UI thread is paused, all other thread may or may not need an explicit interrupt. If the OS needs memory, the activity may get in Stop state or may even get destroyed, however on pressing the back button, it starts again, if destroyed.
4. It's same for `startActivityForResults()` however the calling activity generally do not get destroyed. Sorry I don't know about ASP.Net pages.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. So re item 3, say a thread was created in activity A and a new activity B was started, activity A and any threads it has created will be paused automatically??

Comment: Nope, only the UI Thread (read main Thread) will be paused, while all other thread will continue to run, unless explicitly interpreted either by code or by OS.